# Take data from a specific row

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a form where people can enter in certain dimensional grades for a specific name. So each row of the spreadsheet will probably read something like:

```
Name | Strength | Agility | Luck 
John |     8    |     7   |   1
```

...etc. But John and his peers may be graded many times, so their names will continue to appear down the spreadsheet. I'd like a way to take specific peoples' grades and enter the averages of their dimensions somewhere else in the spreadsheet (or a different spreadsheet). Is there a way for me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use AVERAGEIF :

```
=AVERAGEIF(B4:B6,B10,C4:C6)
```

B4:B6 - column Name
C4:C6 - column Strength (for exmpl.)
B10 - specific name

This function is available only in New Google SpreadSheet: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3256529

Answer (score 0):

Because a Form it may not be advisable to have the condition name in the same column as the range of names (OP has mentioned *their names will continue to appear down the spreadsheet*). This could also be a problem where the ranges are predetermined (eg B4:B6).

However, applying the same function as @jacek2V I would suggest something more like:

```
 =averageif($B:$B,$I2,C:C)
```

in part because also easy to extend to more than a single attribute (ie copied across and down to suit):

[image: WA54647 example]

The above requires that ColumnI in the example is populated with one instance of each name in ColumnB in the example, which might be achieved with:

```
=unique(B:B)
```

in I1.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to current (unaccepted) offers is a pivot table:

[image: WA54647 example]